# Excel 2010 save as webpage - Want Japanese characters in HTML file instead of Unicode

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, html, unicode

For programming purposes (Objective-C) I need to export Japanese characters as a HTML file from Excel so I can parse data into my project. I'm using Excel 2010. For example:

[image: screenshot]

When I open up the saved HTML file all I can see is a bunch of Unicode characters in place of the actual Japanese characters. Is there a way I can:

1. Change settings somewhere in Excel to ensure actual symbols/characters are saved in the HTML file instead of Unicode numbers
2. Convert the saved HTML file so that all Unicode characters are converted into actual symbols

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'd enjoy trying to answer this one. It'd be nice if you could provide the actual file. Nitpick: Unicode characters are "actual characters". It's just that your "actual" characters are in some non-universal character set.

Comment: Sure. For example, I would like to see 飯 rather than &#39151 in the HTML. I'm new here, what's the easiest way to get you the file?

Comment: 飯 is actually a Unicode character. &#39151; (note the semicolon) is an HTML character entity; it's used to enter the Unicode  character in a locale that doesn't support it. / To share the file, upload it to a service such as Dropbox and post the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have Excel saving the HTML using a Western character set. Since 飯 isn't in the character set, it gets translated to &#39151; so the browser interprets it correctly. To disable this translation,

1. Bring up the save as dialog.
2. Click on **Tools/Web Options**. The Web Options dialog appears.[image: web options dialog]
3. On the Encoding tab, the **Save this document as:** dropdown is probably showing "Western European (Windows)" or whatever Western character set you're using. Change this to "Unicode (UTF-8)". You can also change it to a Japanese character set, but UTF-8 is more flexible and does what you want.
4. Save the web page as before.